# Converting array and objects in array to pure array

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => demo1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => demo2
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => otherdemo
        )
)
```

How can I convert the whole array (including objects) to a pure multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I want to use the array in my foreach loop

Comment: `foreach` can be used to iterate over an instance of stdClass just like it can be used to iterate over an array. Given your need, no conversion is required.

Comment: why not use the object in your foreach loop ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have you tried typecasting?

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

There is another trick actually

```
$json  = json_encode($object);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can have more info here [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in the PHP manual, the second parameter is called *assoc*:

> **assoc**
>
> When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Which is exactly what you're looking for.

You may want to try this, too : [Convert Object To Array With PHP (phpro.org)](https://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html)

Comment: `$array = (array) $object;` would not work for inner child elements

Answer (score 10):

Just use this :

```
json_decode(json_encode($yourArray), true);
```

Comment: Ibrahim had already provided this technique back in 2012.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `array_walk` to convert every item from object to array:

```
function convert(&$item , $key)
{
   $item = (array) $item ;
}

array_walk($array, 'convert');
```

Comment: does not work with multidmensional array of objects with array of objects

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get to this pure array format:

```
Array
(
  [1] => "demo1",    
  [2] => "demo2",
  [6] => "otherdemo",
)
```

Then I would do:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $object)
{
    $result[$object->id] = $object->name
}
```

(edit) Actually that's what I was looking for possibly not what the OP was looking for. May be useful to other searchers.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast all objets, something like :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $object)
{
    $result[] = (array) $object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using OOP, the simplest method would be to pull the code to convert itself into an array to the class itself, you then simply call this method and have the returned array populate your original array.

```
class MyObject {

    private $myVar;
    private $myInt;

    public function getVarsAsArray() {

        // Return the objects variables in any structure you need
        return array($this->myVar,$this->myInt);

    }

    public function getAnonVars() {

        // If you don't know the variables
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php for info on `get_object_vars()`

Answer (score 1):

it you have object and you want to set a value as array
use

```
$this->object->pluck('name');
```

then you get the value as array of names like

```
["name1", "name2", "name3"];
```

Comment: Why does this answer completely ignore the OP's provided data?